# WebView2 control not loading HTML string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webview2

[WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) Control: As shown below, the HTML String successfully loads via [NavigateToString(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/wpf/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-webview2#navigatetostring) call inside `Button_Click(...)` event. But I need to have the HTML string loaded as soon as the `Window` and/or its `Grid` is loaded. But the following code either inside the constructor `MainWindow(){...}` or inside `rootGrid_Loadded(...)` event throws the error shown below:

**Question**: How can we have the issue resolved and have the `HTML string` loaded right after either the `Window` or the `Grid` is loaded? Or are there better solutions/workarounds?

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWebView2TEST.MainWindow"
        .....
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Style="{StaticResource CustomWindowStyle}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content=Test" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
        <wv2:WebView2 Name="MyWebView" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**NOTE**: Call to MyLoadHTMLString() in the following constructor or the `rootGrid_Loaded(...)` event throws the error shown below:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyLoadHTMLString();
    }
........
}

private void rootGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MyLoadHTMLString();
}


public void MyLoadHTMLString()
{
    string sHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
    "<html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" +
    "<head>" +
        "<meta charset=\"utf-8\" />" +
        "<title>Test Title</title>" +
    "</head>" +
    "<body>" +
        "<p>Test paragraph</p>" +
    "</body>" +
    "</html>";
MyWebView.NavigateToString(sHTML);
}
```

**NOTE**: Following Button click event `successfully` loads the HTML string into `WebView2`

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MyLoadHTMLString();
}
```

**Error**:

> > System.InvalidOperationException
> > HResult=0x80131509
> > Message=Attempted to use WebView2 functionality which requires its CoreWebView2 prior to the CoreWebView2 being initialized.  Call EnsureCoreWebView2Async or set the Source property first.
> > Source=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf

**UPDATE**:

The second and third paragraph of this [MSDN Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/wpf/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-webview2#navigatetostring) seem to provide some resolution to such an issue. but I'm not sure how to implement it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First:**

The answer to your question:

You must ensure the `Webview2` control is `initialized` before you can use it. You can do this in one of two ways, either call:

```
await MyWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
```

Or simply set the `Source` property.

**Next:**
This is just a good advice. I never use 'NavigateToString', because having html in a C# string can quickly become 'messy'.

Instead I create a subfolder (called 'html'). Then I have a `html` file, a `css` file and a `script` file inside this folder. Now I can edit the files directly and have intellisense and error checking at design time.

**Remember**: Click the files in '`Property Inspector`', then in properties window, select '`Copy to output directory`'. Here select: '`Copy if newer`'. Now the files will be copied to 'Bin' folder, so `WebView2` can find them.

Now in your code, you simple set the WebView2's `Source` property to the path of the html file, like this:

```
MyWebView.Source = new Uri(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Html\MyWebView.html"));
```

Note: This will automatically initialize the WebView2 and navigate to your html file.

In your html file, you can now include css and script files like you normally do for a webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Whatever</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyWebView.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyWebView.js">
    </script>
................
```

This is IMHO a much nicer way to use local html -  much easier to maintain.

Comment: The html string passed to the app is a dynamic string and hence I don't have control over it. Would there be an issue?

Comment: Not an issue. In your question you show a C# string (which I think is messy to read and maintain). If you get the string from elsewhere, it's probably fine (since you don't have to maintain it and don't need intellisense). BTW: Have you got it working?

Comment: Your suggestion works (thank you). I may store that dynamic html first into the folder you suggest and display into webview2 from there. Hope that won't be a performance issue.

Comment: I don't think, you will see any performance difference, I use it all the time. What takes the time is parsing the html, if it's large, simply loading from a local file is fast.

Answer (score 15):

To load a html into `WebView2`, you can use [NavigateToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigatetostring?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.664.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var html = @"
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Basic Web Page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                Hello World!
            </body>
        </html>";

    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    webView21.NavigateToString(html);
}
```

[image]