# CoreWebView2 is null when accessing it from another XAML Window in the same project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webview2

[WPF WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf) Control is inside the `MainWindow.xaml` (shown below). When calling [ExecuteScriptAsync(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/wpf/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-webview2#executescriptasync) from a Button click event inside `MainWindow.xaml.cs` (code shown below), it works fine. But when accessing `WebView2` control from another class `AnotherWindow.xaml.cs` (in the same project) and call the same `ExecuteScriptAsync(...)` method it complains about `CoreWebView2` being null

**Question**: What I may be missing, and how can it be resolved?

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWebView2TEST.MainWindow"
        .....
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Style="{StaticResource CustomWindowStyle}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content=Test" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
        <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Remark 1**: Following works fine when button and its click event is inside `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
private async void btnTest1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();");
}
```

The debug mode shows below that `CoreWebView2` is not null (and hence the code works):

[image]

**Remark 2**: Following does NOT work when button and its click event is inside another window `AnotherWindow.xaml.cs` in the same project but accessing the `WebView2` control of the `MainWindow.xaml`

```
private async void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    await mainWindow.webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();");
}
```

The debug mode inside the `AnotherWindow.xaml.cs` shows below that `CoreWebView2` is not null (and hence throws the error: Object reference not set):

[image]

Comment: It's apparently not yet initialized. The clue may be in the error message in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62975196/1136211): *... Call EnsureCoreWebView2Async or set the Source property first.*

Comment: @Clemens How do we set the Source property for an HTML string. Do you happen to know?

Comment: Did you tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71715892/11888809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the CoreWebView2 as described in [the WebView2 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/wpf/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-webview2):

> Upon creation, the control's CoreWebView2 property will be null. This
> is because creating the CoreWebView2 is an expensive operation which
> involves things like launching Edge browser processes. There are two
> ways to cause the CoreWebView2 to be created: 1) Call the
> EnsureCoreWebView2Async method. This is referred to as explicit
> initialization. 2) Set the Source property (which could be done from
> markup, for example).

From your second question, you cannot use the Source property to provide the HTML of the document. You need to call EnsureCoreWebView2Async, wait for it to complete, and then call  NavigateToString on the CoreWebView2:

```
   await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
   webView.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(htmlString);
```