# How can I initialize the WebView2 in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I'm trying to use WebView2 in a WPF application. I read in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf) and in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62975196/webview2-control-not-loading-html-string) as well, that I should call the `EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` or set the `Source` property in order to initialize the WebView. If I set the `Source`, it loads the web page correctly, but I can't do this way, because I have the html content in memory (and it's not allowed to write to disk).

So I tried to call the initialization method:

```
var webView = new WebView2();

webView.NavigationCompleted += Navigation_Completed;
webView.Initialized += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) => { 
    webView.NavigateToString(myHtml);
});

await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
```

Running of this code is blocked by the `EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` method. I can even wait for one minute, but nothing happens, it's just stuck in initialization. No exception, no error message.
I run this code on UI thread, but the same thing happened when I called this method on another thread.

Does anyone experienced this behavior? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the `WebView2` manually, you must add it to the `Controls` collection of the form.

When you drop a WebView2 on the form, the designer does this automatically.

Simply call:

```
Controls.Add(webView)
await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
```

Now you should be able to display your html.

**Update**:

You can still drop the `WebView2` on your form, if you prefer, just **don't set the `Source` property.**

Then you can use the designer to assign event handlers and in `Initialized` event you call:

```
webView.NavigateToString(myHtml);
```

just as you do now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to go to a specific URI, I had to do the following calls.

As previously noted, do not set the `Source` attribute in your XAML.

Note that `wv` is the `Name` of my `WevView2`. Important part is that you still need to wait for the CoreWebView2 to be loaded. Now you can put any URI string in place of "https://www.microsoft.com"

```
    private async void wv_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       await wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
       wv.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.microsoft.com");
    }
```

Comment: of course, you should call the `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` function. My problem was solved by adding the webView to the visual tree, by `Controls.Add(webView)`

Answer (score 0):

A proper place to initialize webview2 is on WPF OnContentRendered()
Example:

```
   protected override async void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
   {
        base.OnContentRendered(e);

        var webView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync();
        await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);

   }
```