# How to create custom windows in a WPF / WebView2 application when window.open is called?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.1, webview2

I have a Webview2 app that needs to be able to intercept `window.open` calls and configure the resulting window in a certain way (e.g. make it non-resizable, frameless, remove the default location bar that appears, etc).

So far, I know that I need to intercept the [`NewWindowRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.newwindowrequested?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49) event and assign the `NewWindow` property of the `EventArgs` to the new Webview2 control, however I'm having trouble getting this to work, and I haven't found any documentation listing an example that attempts this.

I'm using WPF.

Note also that I'm new to both WPF and WebView2, so maybe something I'm doing is totally non-sensical.

This is roughly my code:

```
public static async void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e) {
    var obj = e.GetDeferral(); // I think I need to do this to ensure that the resulting window ends up as the return of window.open
    var win = new System.Windows.Window(); // create my WPF window
    var w = new WebView2(); // create my Webview control
    win.Content = w; // site the Webview control?

    await w.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(MainWindow.Webview.CoreWebView2.Environment);

    e.NewWindow = w.CoreWebView2;
    obj.Complete();
}
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the `Task` returned by `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` never completes.

Am I setting this up correctly? Why doesn't `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` resolve?

Comment: Try: `public async void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested` then you can `await`.

Comment: But won't an exception inside of an `async void` crash the process? I mean I guess I can wrap everything in try/catch, but kind of annoying; maybe that's what I'll do though. @PoulBak

Comment: The `async void` is specifically made for eventhandlers and should only be used for that. When you don't `await` it's 'fire and forget'.

Comment: @PoulBak Ok, I'll update my code. Though it doesn't fix my issue

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139090/how-can-i-initialize-the-webview2-in-wpf/65176665#65176665

Comment: @PoulBak I'm not sure which `Controls` property they're talking about. My `System.Windows.Window` object doesn't have `Controls`, only `Content`. Not sure what `Controls` refers to exactly. I vaguely recall using that for a `Form`, but I'm not using WinForms here

Comment: @PoulBak It seems that calling `win.Show()` makes it work and the Task completes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I had to call `win.Show()` to make the `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` `Task` complete.

Perhaps I'll really want to only show the window after the webview content has loaded, but this is a good start at least.