# WebView2 - NavigateToString does not render images

Tags: c#, webview2

I created a webView2 object and called a `CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(string htmlpage)` to render an HTML file (stored in memory as a string). The method renders all the HTML page except that the background image and the button images are not. No issues with the html page; i can see the images with both Edge and chrome browsers.

This issue did not happen with the old `WebBrowser` object. Is that a bug, or is there any other extra step to make the `NavigateToString` render images?

Comment: Where do the images come from? Show the html/css that fetches them. Remember that `NavigateToString` causes the url to be `about:blank`, so you can't use relative links.

Comment: An alternative approach, which should work for you is to load html from a file. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62975196/webview2-control-not-loading-html-string - that will load images, css etc from the same folder with relative links.

Comment: The images are stored in the C drive. I set the background image in the body this way   `background-image: url("C:/ProgramData/MyFolder/image.PNG");`. 
The images for the buttons are set as fallows : 
`img src="file://C:\ProgramData\MyFolder\button.ico" `
Again, the HTML/CSS is fine and loads correctly with Edge or Chrome. Something is wrong with the `NavigateToString` method since only the images are missing.     

Thanks again for your help

Comment: I looked at you post and i don't think it is a good solution for me. The application i am working on pulls the screen definitions from the database in order to build the html pages (as strings). I don't see the need to store them on the hard drive then load them back again to the application. I would have also to create a cache folder by user that will store html pages for the entire application.

Comment: Ok, try to press 'F12' to get the developer tools open. That might give you some hint, what is wrong.

Comment: That's an awesome tool. I can see two errors related to the images: "Not allowed to load local resource". It looks like it is a permission issue. Not sure yet why ...

Comment: That explains it. It's only allowed to load local resources when the protocol for the html  is `file://` The old WebBrowser was based on IE7, which had terrible security. The only solution I can come up with is to move scripts, css and images to a public webserver and load them from there.

Comment: apparently, this is a known issue that was resolved with the `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping` method. This allows you to assign a local folder to a domain name. I am trying to learn how to set it up ...

Comment: It worked using `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping`. I was able to stick an image on a button. The thing is that the fie:// needs to be replaced with https://   

[link](https://laptrinhx.com/taking-the-new-chromium-webview2-control-for-a-spin-in-net-part-1-535259649/)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay before doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As well as using SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping you can convert your images to base64.
Here's an example:

```
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```